# How can I install elementary OS on a 64-bit system that only supports 32-bit UEFI?

Tags: uefi

I got elementary OS and found that although my device (Lenovo Flex 10) though has a 64-bit processor it does not support 64-bit UEFI and has no legacy boot options.

I found how to solve a similar problem, but with a different OS. Can someone explain how to follow these instructions for elementary OS?

http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/how-cool-lenovo-flex-10-netbook-and-how-install-linux-32-bit-uefi-system/

[image]

Comment: It's the same as in the article you referenced. Just copy the bootia32.efi file in the EFI/boot directory on the flash drive

Comment: I have the same problem with a CSL Narrow Box 4k !
[![CSL Narrow Box 4k](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Y9ONM5yIL._AC_SL1500_.jpg)](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Y9ONM5yIL._AC_SL1500_.jpg) https://www.amazon.de/Mini-PC-lautlose-Silent-PC-Bluetooth/dp/B01EYN55JO CSL Narrow Box 4K / Silent-PC mit 2GB RAM, Intel QuadCore Atom CPU 1840MHz, 32GB SSD, Intel HD Graphik, WLAN, USB 3.1, HDMI, SD, Bluetooth, Windows 10 I asume they got CHEAPER conditions for the 32-bit version of the Windows which came with the Narrow Box than for a 64-bit version. MfG, MEX